# How to disable all power management in Ubuntu (for a server netbook)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electrical-power

I need to **disable** everything related to having the netbook-server go into sleep/hibernate/shutdown.  Spinning down the disks during inactivity is fine, but it is crucial that the machine remain in a state where it maintains connectivity over wi-fi (and the internet at large), as well as keep the USB subsystem up and operational (we're running a hardware modem off of it).

Context:

- The netbook is not phyiscally accessible (it is in Thailand, I am
  not).
- I have SSH access only
- It is running vanilla Ubuntu 10.04 32
  Bit
- It is a netbook of the Asus eeePC variety

Is that possible to do via the command line without causing significant/any downtime?

Comment: A "server netbook"? Holy silicon! Why haven't you installed the server version of Ubuntu?

Comment: This has disaster written all over it. I have a feeling this is probably not the best solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable those power management features at various level.

**Graphical User Interface level**

In GNOME, you should edit the following file:

```
sudoedit  /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

One section concerns the suspend function and the other the hibernate one. Each as a tag  that you have to set to no:

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

**Keyboard level**

Now, to avoid the problem if the keyboard has some related keys for these features, you have to enter the following command:

```
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/hibernate -t string interactive
```

**Command line level**

It would still be possible to trigger a suspend or hibernation from the command line, here is how to disable it.

We have to create an executable script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` that will cancel any hibernate or suspend actions.

```
sudoedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/000cancel-hibernate-suspend
```

The content of this file should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prevents hibernation and suspend
. "$PM_FUNCTIONS"
case "${1}" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    inhibit
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

Now make that file executable:

```
chmod 0755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/000cancel-hibernate-suspend
```

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I successfully used the following to disable suspend:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: After disable suspend, and close the laptop, some programs like fail2ban and systemd were to 100% cpu loads..

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement

> Then there are event manager daemons apmd and acpid
>
> They provide means to execute commands on these external events. They
>   run the scripts they find in their config directory tree under
>   /etc/acpi, or /etc/apm respectively.
>
> The package acpi-support provides a set of such scripts under
>   /etc/acpi that deal with handling special acpi buttons on laptops.
>
> The package pm-utils provides the pm-action, pm-hibernate, pm-suspend
>   and pm-suspend-hybrid commands. They allow to trigger hard power
>   management events by software. The pm-tools also provide script
>   directories to hook-in other software when switching power (saving)
>   states.
>
> The gnome-power-manager is a program with a graphical user interface
>   that subscribes itself to power events and acts on them. It shows you
>   the battery status on laptops and dims down the screen if on battery
>   for example. It will also shutdown or hibernate the computer after
>   some idle time or before the battery runs out, if a user is logged in.

Try just uninstalling some of those, using apt-get remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `/etc/default/acpi-support`. You can enable or disable features there.  Setting `SUSPEND_METHODS="none"` will disable suspending by the apci-support tools.

Later, you can run:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/acpi-support restart
```

On the other hand, the acpid daemon will check `/etc/defaults/acpi-support` for knowing what it has/can do.